# Imbalanced classification or Regression? What is the best approach to my A/B testing related problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes, ab-test

The context of the problem is A/B testing of two new versions of a game. I have a structured dataset (50000 rows x 22 columns) from the game designers that represents data with respect to two versions of the game: A and B. The rows represent individual players, and there are several categorical features (c*) and continuous features (n*). One of the important columns is the monetization (in-game purchases) obtained from the players. **The end goal is to be able to recommend a version A or B to *each* player, such that the monetization would be maximized.**

```
raw_df_columns: 'id', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'game_version', 'n1', 'n2',
'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9', 'n10', 'n11', 'n12', 'n13',
'monetization'
```

**Issues:**

The most important problem is that the version of the game (A or B) in the 'game_version' column is *not the end label*. It is simply the version that was issued to the person. I do not have the required labels directly to model it as a classification problem.

Therefore my initial approach to this was to attempt it as a regression problem. I did an EDA, eliminated some non-essential features and tried to predict 'monetization' using the rest of the features (except 'id' which has no correlation). The prediction accuracy is very good, but the problem is that the feature 'game_version' is more or less being ignored in this prediction. Or with some ML models it seems to have a very simplistic relationship, which is wrong.

Finally, in most cases A is better than B (has more monetization than the best of B), except for a small minority (~ 190 cases out of 50000) where B is better than A. This also makes it very difficult for the ML algorithms to zero in on such cases.

**Ask:**

What is the best approach that I should take for this problem? How do I obtain the *recommended* version of the game for a given player?

I can also provide additional details or clarifications if needed. Thanks in advance!

Edited:

Included sample of data. **N14 is monetization.**
[image]

Comment: Can you include a sample of your data, even if it is faked? My recommendation can be more concrete if I understand what I’m working with.

Comment: Sure @Demetri. Just added.

Comment: Good question. Just an idea: Can you (looking at the distribution of the n14) come up with a threshold (separately for A and B), and: if the n14 is below the threshold, mark it as wrong label (it was A, but should be B) and if above as correct (it was A and should be A). Then you will have the *end labels* and you can proceed as with an unbalanced classification task.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Hans. Interesting approach. But I am thinking of a couple of caveats. First: would we assume that (for the test data) the monetization is known? 
Second: If I come up with the distribution and the threshold to mark the right and wrong labels, then what i be training an unbalanced classification for? it seems that I have a simple greater than or less than threshold if condition.

Answer (score 1):

(Since you describe this an an AB test, I am assuming that you randomly recommend each game type. If the players choose the game type, then there is an additional layer of complexity that my answer does not address.)

You are off to a good start by making a predictive model of `monetization` with high (validated) predictive accuracy, and that is where I would start. However, your goal is not to predict the `monetization` value given that a player has selected a paricular game. Your goal is to recommend the game in order to get the highest `monetization` value.

Thus, I would take the known characteristics (the value of the features other than the game) and make predictions using each game version. Then the game version yielding the highest predicted `monetization` is the game version to recommend. You might want some kind of interval estimate for the difference in predicted `monetization` between recommending each game. Given your comment that the game version seems not to be an important feature, it might be that these intervals show neither game version to yield much of a higher `monetization` than the other.

Aside from the interval estimate, it sounds like this is exactly what you are doing, so I think your strategy seems to be a reasonable one. To address some specific questions...

> but the problem is that the feature 'game_version' is more or less being ignored in this prediction

It might be that the game version just is not that important. This seems like valuable information.

> Finally, in most cases A is better than B (has more monetization than the best of B), except for a small minority (~ 190 cases out of 50000) where B is better than A.

It sounds like game version `A` is associated with greater `monetization`. While I struggle to reconcile this with the previous point, my interpretation is that game version `A` is usually going to lead to more money and should be the recommended game in the absence of highly compelling evidence that game version `B` should be recommended.